# Loading class using a Class instance

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any simple way, to load a class given a class instance?
I know that I can load a class by calling

```
Class.forName(nameOfClass);
```

where the `nameOfClass` is the name of the class which I want to be loaded.

I also know that by instantiating a class this way

```
clazz.newInstance();
```

where `clazz` is an instance of `Class`, the class loads if it was not loaded before, but I don't want to instantiate if it's not necessary.

My question is that, is there any **simple** way to load a class given a `Class` instance?

I could solve the problem this way:

```
try {
    Class.forName(clazz.getName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    assert false : "No way!";
}
```

but I think this is overcomplicated.

Comment: If you have an instance of a class, this means that the class is already loaded, isn't it?

Comment: I have an instance of the `Class` class, but not the other one, which I want to load.

Comment: I think you may be confused.  You have an *instance* of `Class`, which corresponds to the class that you want to load.  If you call, for example, `Class.forName("my.Foo")`, then you have loaded `my.Foo`, and the `Class` instance you have *is* the class of `Foo`.

Comment: Yes. I know @AndrzejDoyle, but didn't wanted to use any Strings or try-catches etc., just a simple method call, if it's possible.

Comment: @BartisÁron You're trying to load a class that's already loaded. Period. You can't call `clazz.getName()` on a class that's not already loaded.

Comment: @Bartis I don't think you understood my comment.  If you have a class instance, **the class is already loaded**.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle No... I don't have the instance of that class. I only have the instance of `Class` class, which describes the class which I want to load.

Comment: That *is* the instance of that class's class.  It doesn't just "describe" the class, it *is* that class.  The only thing that describes the class (without actually *being* the class), is its name as a String.  And the only way to go from that name to a `Class` instance, is by loading the class.

Comment: You seem to understand that `Class.forName(className)` loads a class, given its name.  Since you have a `Class` instance, this step has been done already - if not explicitly by you, then by some other code - and thus the class has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> I don't want to instantiate... just load
>   the class –  Bartis Áron 15 mins ago

Then you can just do fallow:

Add method yo your class:

```
public static final void init() {    
}
```

And then just call it:

```
YourClass.init();
```

Comment: Well... That's a solution... I don't wanted to make any unnecessary method call, but it works and it's simpler. ((-: I couldn't be precise enough despite all my efforts. q-: Anyway, answer accepted.